# Use two ArrayAdapter in the same ListView

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter, android-logcat

I have these activities: `CoffeeActivity` and `DrinkActivity`

This is my main activity, which has a ListView

```
public class CalculationHistoryListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Save saveData;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList arrayListdrink,arrayListCoffee;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculation_history_list);

        // Toasts the test ad message on the screen. Remove this after defining your own ad unit ID.
       // Toast.makeText(this, TOAST_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       //sqlite database 
        saveData = new Save(CalculationHistoryListActivity.this);

        //listview 
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            //coffee list
            arrayListCoffee = saveData.getAllCoffeeCalculation();
            ArrayAdapter coffeeArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(CalculationHistoryListActivity.this,
                    R.layout.list_view_item_coffee, R.id.total_money_coffee, arrayListCoffee);
            listView.setAdapter(coffeeArrayAdapter);

        //drink list
        arrayListdrink = saveData.getAllDrinkCalculation();
        ArrayAdapter drinkArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(CalculationHistoryListActivity.this,
                R.layout.list_view_item_coffee, R.id.total_money_drink,arrayList);
                listView.setAdapter(drinkArrayAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_calculation_history_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

This is my Database Helper

```
public class Save extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my.db";
    private static final String TABLE = "mytable";
    private static final String COFFEE = "coffee";
    private static final String DRINK = "drink";

    public Save(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String query ;
        query = "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE+ "(" +COFFEE+ " TEXT, " +DRINK+ " TEXT " + ")";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" DROP FILE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

    }

    //this is coffee section
    public boolean addDatabaseToCoffee(int i){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COFFEE,i);
        long chaker = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE,null,contentValues);
        if (chaker == -1){
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }

    }
    //this is drink section
    public boolean addDatabaseToDrink(int i){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DRINK,i);

        long chaker = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE,null,contentValues);
        if (chaker == -1){
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }

    }


    //coffee
    public ArrayList<String> getAllCoffeeCalculation() {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE,null);
        res.moveToFirst();

        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COFFEE)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
    //drink
    public ArrayList<String> getAllDrinkCalculation() {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE,null);
        res.moveToFirst();

        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){

            //array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(DRINK)));

            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }

}
```

My problem is that I have two Activities, and when I use the Coffee or drink Activity for a single time it's OK, but if I want to use two Activities both at once, my app crashes

> My LogCat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:401)
                                                                           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3065)
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1945)
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:719)
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:785)
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1735)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2852)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
                                                                           at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:2537)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
```

Comment: You cannot use two adapters in the same ListView, but that is unrelated to your error

Comment: you have one listview and try to set it to two arrayAdapter...    listView.setAdapter(coffeeArrayAdapter);    &  listView.setAdapter(drinkArrayAdapter); Why?

Comment: @shanyour because i have a two activity one is CoffeeActivity And Secand is Drink Activity in coffee or drink activity user can calculate there price or etc.  ok i explain more when user click number 1 Coffee activity then they have calculated price and go next 2 activity to price preview and before save to sure to user that data are he want to save. and then 3rd activity save data in database and show as a listview. and this 3rd activity are the all calculation show if user save coffee price then this activity show or user save drink price then hear are show that's why i need to save to value

Comment: and sorry for my English skill it's not good sorry for that @shanyour

Comment: so what is the way to use multiple adapter in listview ? and can you please tell me how to solve this error ? @cricket_007

Answer (score 2):

Your error is coming from **inside** the Adapter.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
  -->     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:401)
  -->     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
  -->     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3065)
```

---

Firstly, your drink list is empty... you commented this line

```
//array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(DRINK)));
```

And what is `arrayList` here?

```
arrayListdrink = saveData.getAllDrinkCalculation();
ArrayAdapter drinkArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(CalculationHistoryListActivity.this,
        R.layout.list_view_item_coffee, R.id.total_money_drink,arrayList);
                                                               ^^^
```

And you should `DROP TABLE`, not `FILE`...

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" DROP FILE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
```

If your database worked, then I see nothing else wrong with what you have. Clear your app data to recreate the database, fix these issues, then you *should* see a list of drink values.

---

Anyways, no you cannot show two Adapters in one ListView.

You can however add both columns of your database to one ArrayList and display both in one adapter.

```
// coffee and drink
public ArrayList<String> getAllCoffeeCalculation() {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE,null);
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        String c = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COFFEE));
        String d = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(DRINK));

        array_list.add(c + "\t" + d);
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

Then, in the Activity.

```
saveData = new Save(CalculationHistoryListActivity.this);

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

arrayListCoffee = saveData.getAllCoffeeCalculation();
ArrayAdapter<String> coffeeArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
      CalculationHistoryListActivity.this,
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
      arrayListCoffee);
listView.setAdapter(coffeeArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @crinket_007

Comment: but it's not solve my problem but can you tell me if i 
       if (coffeeArrayAdapter != null){
           //print coffee
           listView.setAdapter(coffeeArrayAdapter);
       }else if (drinkArrayAdapter != null){
           //print drink
           listView.setAdapter(drinkArrayAdapter);                                                                           i try to solve my self like this but it's not working can you please tell me there are way to working singel activity a singel time not bothworking on the same time

Comment: Neither of your adapter object can be null. You explicitly made a `new ArrayAdapter`. I do not know what you want to see on the ListView, but my answer is just one *possible* solution to your issue.